# Errors when inserting date and time into QODBC query C#

Tags: c#, datetime, insert, odbc, qodbc

I am getting an error

> ERROR [42500] ERROR: 3020 - There was an error when converting the date value "0000-00-48. In the field "salesOrder Transaction Date

The date value I am trying to insert is `4/4/2018`.

My code

```
DateTime JobDate = Wintac_JobDate;

string addSalesOrder = "INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (CustomerRefListID, TemplateRefListID," +
                       " SalesOrderLineItemRefListID, SalesOrderLineDesc,SalesOrderLineQuantity, SalesOrderLineRate, " +
                       "SalesOrderLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID, Memo, SalesOrderLineInventorySiteRefListID, SalesOrderLineInventorySiteLocationRefListID" +
                       ", TxnDate, ShipAddressAddr1, ShipAddressAddr2, ShipAddressAddr3, ShipAddressAddr4, ShipAddressAddr5, FQSaveToCache)" +
                       "VALUES('" + QBCustomerListID + "','" + templateLID + "', '" + LID + "', '" + Description + "', " + Quantity + ", " + 120 +  "," +
                                    " '" + SalesTax + "', '" +Wintac_WipNo+"','"+LaborSite+"','"+LaborSiteLocation+"',"+
                                    "?,'" + shipAdr1+ "','" + shipAdr2 + "','" + shipAdr3 + "','" + shipAdr4 + "','" + shipAdr5 + "'," +
                                    ""+ FQSaveToCache + ")";


OdbcCommand sqlcmd2 = new OdbcCommand(addSalesOrder, quickbookscon2);

sqlcmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlcmd2.CommandTimeout = 180;

MessageBox.Show(JobDate.ToShortDateString());
sqlcmd2.Parameters.Add("P7", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = JobDate

if (Quantity != 0)
{
   if (sqlcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
   {
       if(FQSaveToCache == 0)
          MessageBox.Show(" added successfully.");
   }
}
  sqlcmd2.Dispose()
```

I have tried converting the variable Job Date

- Date Time
- short date string
- long date string
- entering the variable directly into the query

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is on that line;

```
sqlcmd2.Parameters.Add("P7", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = JobDate.ToLongDateString()
```

You try to insert *string* representation on a `DateTime` typed column. That's *quite* wrong. You need to directly pass your DateTime value instead of passing it string representation. To learn this as a habit, please read [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Other than this, I saw a few problem also in your code:

1. You should always use [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
2. Use [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to dispose your connection and commmand automatically instead of callind `Dispose` method manually which you didn't *even* consider to do in your code.

Comment: Ok thanks but I already tried using Job Date directly as a DateTime it did not work the exact same error displays. Also I am disposing the connection I just did not copy that part of the code into my question.